# Using onMissingTemplate in lieu of stub cfm files

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, application.cfc

In our ColdFusion application each request goes through index.cfm

Application.cfc decides form the query and form parameters which componetes the user is actually wanted.  Those components are instantiated and the content is dropped through OnRequestStart.

Rather than always hit index.cfm with a query/form parameter, for simple cases, we would like to hit a "missing" cfm (i.e. MyApp.cfm) and allow the OnMissingTemplate function parse out the fact that we really want the content of a component (i.e. MyApp).

Another way to do this would be to actualy put cfm stub files in for "generic" calls to the components but it seems like with OnMissingTemplate we do not need to do that.

Is this a reasonable use for OnMissingTemplate?

Comment: Appears to be a repeat of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794221/can-clean-urls-be-achieved-in-a-pure-coldfusion-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great use for onMissingTemplate. Just make sure that if you're using IIS, that you make sure that the files you're linking to are actually .cfm (MyApp.cfm) files, and not directories (/MyApp/). See these links for more information:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1625-ColdFusion-8-s-OnMissingTemplate-So-Close-To-Being-Good.htm

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1694-ColdFusion-s-OnMissingTemplate-Event-Handler-Works-With-CFC-Requests.htm