# Is it possible to rewrite url using ColdFusion?

Tags: url, iis, coldfusion, url-rewriting, coldfusion-10

I have got a requirement for generating user friendly urls.I am on IIS.

My dynamic URLs looks like,

`www.testsite.com/blog/article.cfm?articleid=4432`

Client wants the urls should look like

`www.testsite.com/blog/article_title`

I know this can be easily done using IIS URL rewiter 2.0.

But the Client wants to do it using ColdFusion only. Basic idea he given like,

1. User will hit the url `www.testsite.com/blog/article_title`
2. I need to fetch the article id using the article_title in the url.
3. Using the ID to call the article.cfm page and load the output into cfsavecontent and then deliver that output to the browser.

But I do not think its possible at application server level. How IIS will understand our user friendly urls . OR am I missing something important? Is it possible to do it using ColdFusion at application server level?

Comment: Why does the client *care* how it's effected? And why do they want to implement it using the lesser of the two options? You should leave it to the web server to handle URL routing, and leave CF to do the request processing.

Comment: I said this to a fellow the other day: If the client is not a programmer, they don't even understand what you're talking about. If the client is a programmer, they should want you to do this the right (and reliable way).

Comment: @AdamCameron: I completely agree with you , But the client is not ready to implement it at webserver level. I found one blog http://www.garyrgilbert.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/1/2/Coldfusion-Mod-Rewrite , But I am not sure is it a feasible solution or not . Handling it using 404 page is a good solution?

Comment: It might be a bit slow. TBH, I have never tried this sort of thing because I simply *wouldn't*. I'd use modrewrite or similar on my web server. It's not the app server's job to do this sort of thing, and I would flatly refused to pander to a misguided client if they were trying to force my hand in this way. I can't help much here beyond saying "just don't do it that way", and I know you don't want that sort of answer.

Comment: To whomever did so: why did you downvote this without explaining why? That's not very helpful, and kinda counter to the spirit of StackOverflow, innit? UPVOTING to cancel it out.

Comment: If the client does not want `.cfm` in the URL, there is no way this can be done using ColdFusion. It MUST be done at the web server level. Without a rewrite rule at the web server level, the web server will simply look for a file at `/blog/article_title`...which does not exist.

Comment: @ScottStroz , you are absolutely Correct. Lets see if the client understands.

Comment: Deepak, of course you can use CF to process _any file extension_ so if you want your site to be full of .html file (for example) you may do so and still leverage CF. There's nothing magical about a ".cfm" file extension. Such an undertaking might require a bit of refactoring, but you sound like you are doing that any way with all the hoops you are jumping through to rewrite.

Answer (score 4):

First, I hate to recommend reinventing the wheel. Webservers do this and do this well.

Cold Fusion can do something like this with `#cgi.path_info#`. You can jump through some hoops as Adam Tuttle explains here: [Can I have 'friendly' url's without a URL rewriter in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677895/can-i-have-friendly-urls-without-a-url-rewriter-in-iis/3680065#3680065).

---

Option #2: My Favorite: OnMissingTemplate..

Only available to users of Application.cfc (I'm pretty sure .cfm has no counterpart to onMissingTemplate).

You can use this function within application.cfc and all affected pages will throw any "missing" urls at this event. You can then place

```
<cffunction name="onMissingTemplate">
        <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required=true/>
        <!--- Use a try block to catch errors. --->
        <cftry>
                <cfset local.pagename = listlast(cgi.script_name,"/")>
                <cfswitch expression="#listfirst(cgi.script_name,"/")#">
                    <cfcase value="blog">
                        <cfinclude template="mt_blog.cfm">
                        <cfreturn true />
                    </cfcase>
                </cfswitch>
                <cfreturn false />
                <!--- If no match, return false to pass back to default handler. --->
                <cfcatch>
                      <!--- Do some error logging here --->
                      <cfreturn false />
                </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

`mt_blog.cfm` can have contents like, if your url is say just like /blog/How-to-train-your-flea-circus.cfm

```
<!--- get everything after the slash and before the dot --->
<cfset pagename = listfirst(listlast(cgi.script_name,"/"),".")>

<!--- you may probably cache queries blog posts --->
<cfquery name="getblogpost">
  select bBody,bTitle,bID
    from Blog
   where urlname = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#pagename#">
</cfquery>

<!--- This assumes you will have a field, ex: urlname, that has a url-friendly format to match
      to. The trouble is that titles are generically, in most blogs, changing every special char
      to - or _, so it's difficult to change them back for this sort of comparison, so an add'l
      db field is probably best. It also makes it a little easier to make sure no two blogs have
      identical (after url-safe-conversion) titles. --->

...
```

Or if you use a url like /blog/173_How-to-train-your-flea-circus.cfm (where 173 is a post ID)

```
<!--- get everything after the slash and before the dot --->
<cfset pageID = listfirst(listlast(cgi.script_name,"/"),"_")>

<!--- you may probably cache queries blog posts --->
<cfquery name="getblogpost">
  select bBody,bTitle,bID
    from Blog
   where bID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#pageID#">
</cfquery.

...
```

Comment: I have also developed a similar kind of solution like this, but the client do not want the `.cfm` extension in the url.That the problem

Comment: Tell the client they are forcing your hand to provide a very substandard solution, and they really ought to think twice about second-guessing common sense and community advice.

Comment: I agree with Adam. There are tools for tasks and you should use them. When the tools are free, there's no fair argument a client can make against them, because they likely don't even understand what they're arguing against.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend using a missing file handler (or CF's `onMissingTemplate`). Otherwise IIS will return a 404 status code and your page will not be indexed by search engines.

What you need to do is identify a unique prefix pattern you want to use and create a `web.config` rewrite rule.  Example: I sometimes use "/detail_"+id for product detail pages.

You don't need to retain a physical "/blog" sub-directory if you don't want to. Add the following rewrite rule to the web.config file in the web root to accept anything after `/blog/` in the URL and interpret it as `/?blogtitle=[everythingAfterBlog]`. (I've added an additional clause in case you want to continue to support `/blog/article.cfm` links.)

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Blog" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="blog/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^.*(blog/article.cfm).*$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/?blogtitle={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

I recommend using a "301 Redirect" to the new SEO-friendly URL. I also advise using dashes (-) between word fragments and ensure that the character case is consistent (ie, lowercase) or you could get penalized for "duplicate content".

Answer (score 1):

To add to what cfqueryparam suggested, this post on [Using ColdFusion to Handle 404 errors](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2006/6/13/404.errors) shows how to replace the *web server's* 404 handler with a CFM script - giving you full rewrite capabilities. It is for an older version of IIS, but you should be able to find the proper settings in the IIS version you are using.

As Adam and other's have said (and the same point is made in the post) this is not something you should do if you can avoid it. Web servers working at the HTTP level are much better equipped to do this efficiently. When you rely on CF to do it you are intentionally catching errors that are thrown in order to get the behavior you want. That's expensive and unnecessary. Typically the issue with most clients or stakeholders is a simple lack of understanding or familiarity with technology like url rewriting. See if you can bend them a little. Good luck! :)

Comment: I apologize for the missing images in that post. as I said it is very very old :)

Comment: Ok, I went back and resnipped from an old server so the post now has images that match the instructions. Just keep in mind it is for IIS 6 or earlier. In IIS 7+ you would go to the Error cpl and have 3 choices (file, url or 302). Choose the middle "URL" choice - after that the instructions will match.