# Friendly URL with Coldfusion help required

Tags: url-rewriting, coldfusion, seo

After hours in Google, I can't find a step-by-step for friendly URLs with Coldfusion in shared hosting environment with no access to IIS and application.cfm (rather than .cfc).

[Scenario 1: What I have]

www.testsite.com/article.cfm?id=32
- article.cfm looks up article by id and returns full results

What I need to change this to:

www.testsite.com/blog/article-title

I must have this format because I am moving a wordpress site to coldfusion and there are hundreds of blog posts with this format (WordPress and PHP must have done the url rewrite?). I have to retain these URLs for the site.

Question 1: I don't have access to IIS admin to create the rules for IIS Rewrite (it IS turned on), I must hard-code them in the web.config.

Question 2: Do I have to create a "blog" folder?

[Scenario 1: What I have]

www.testsite.com/team.cfm?id=17
- team.cfm looks up member by id and returns full results

What I need to change this to:

www.testsite.com/team/person-name

I guess this is similar to the first scenario.

Please help. I'm not a newbie to Coldfusion but I am a COMPLETE newbie to SEO friendly URLs.

Comment: No ... not a duplicate. He says it "can be easily done using IIS URL rewriter 2.0." Well, I can't figure out the easily done thing. If I use IIS URL rewriter, where is it getting the article-title from? I'm not passing it in the URL, just the ID. Is this what I'm supposed to be doing?

Comment: You may find what you need here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433655/coldfusion-iis-rewrite

Comment: You need to pass a string in the URL (the search-engine friendly title), instead of a numeric ID.

Comment: @TheMegatronMan I've added a recommendation to the previous question (w/web.config sample code) and it should answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342976/693068